# C# Webservice Webmethod without statement/argument

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod

So I need to get rid of the CustomContent tags, is there a way I can remove them? I know it's possible in other webservices and they are not compatible with the current company software. This is a request and I have to keep receiving data.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <CustomName xmlns="http://localhost/">
          <CustomContent>xml</CustomContent>
        </CustomName>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I want to change that to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CustomName xmlns="http://localhost/">xml</CustomName>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Comment: is it a response xml?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about that part. No it's the request

Comment: @TinneS Are you receiving the xml as input to your webservice and want to remove the node from that xml?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where and when is this XML generated? Do you need a proxy changing it after the fact?

Comment: No I want to completely get rid of the tag while still being able to receive data, please read my response to nvoigt @nvoigt The XML is generated on the sample page of the webmethod.